# Postgreql avg on JSON query

Tags: json, postgresql

I have this query that gives me a list of values from a JSON type column. Now I have two questions

1. Is this approach correct to access nested JSON elements?
2. How would I now get the average of my `values`?

```
select json_extract_path_text(json_extract_path(report_data, 'outer_key'), 'inner_key') as values
from report
where serial_number like '%123456%';
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `inner_key` is a number, you can simply cast it to a numeric type:

```
select avg((report_data->'outer_key'->>'inner_key')::float8)
from report
where serial_number like '%123456%';
```